# IOS causing an unwanted line break in HTML

Tags: html, ios, css, line-breaks

I am currently working on a website that has a phone number in the navbar. For some reason the phone number splits into 2 lines on my ipad (which is the only IOS device I have but I assume it is the same on all of them). The phone number appears correctly on every other device I have tried. I have tried just about every solution I could think of including CSS display properties, white-space property and div widths.

How it should look (and does on every other device)

Office: (555) 555-5555

Emergency: (555) 555-5554

How it looks on IOS

Office:

(555) 555-5555

Emergency:

(555) 555-5554

I believe there is something fishy going on with the numbers. If I replace the numbers with a sentence then everything appears as it should on 2 lines. I have tried removing the : and () as well as spaces. Nothing seems to fix this problem as long as the numbers remain.

```css
.phone-number {
 position: fixed;
 top: 10px;
 right: 4%;
 font-size: 1.2em;
 text-align: right;
 display: inline;
 font-family: 'lemonade_icgbold', cursive;
}
```

```html
<div class="phone-number">
    Office: (555) 555-5555<br>
    Emergency: (555) 555-5554
</div>
```

I really appreciate your help!

Keenan

Comment: Have you also tried `&nbsp;`?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the string within a tag.  For example:

```
<div class="phone-number">
<p>Office: (555) 555-5555<br></p>
<p>Emergency: (555) 555-5554<p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation! Sadly that still didn't fix the issue :(

Comment: Ahh!  This is most likely due to the sizing of the display not the code.  Are you using Bootstrap?

Comment: I am not using the bootstrap.css file but I have coded it essentially the same way as bootstrap.

Comment: I wonder if there is a property in the navbar somewhere that is actually causing the problem.

Comment: What if you removed postion: fixed; ?

Comment: On the browser it is fine.  On my iPhone I only see the mobile version.  It has a button for the phone but does not seems to work.  I do not have a tablet to inspect it beyond this.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for your help! I really appreciate it! I will keep toying around with it to see what I can do to fix it. (The mobile button was the next item on my to fix list but so far I have been frustrated with the entire div!)

Comment: Temporarily link it to Bootstrap just to see how it acts.  Sorry that I couldn't help!

Comment: Have you solved this?